# Giving padding to an element increases total width

Tags: css

I have a div and I want to indent my text, say `40px` from the left. For that, I write

```
#rightheader{
    float: right;
    width: 70%;   
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #336699;
    padding-top: 20px; 
}
```

Now, the confusion is that whenever I add `padding-left: 40px;` into the above, the total width of the div also incresases. Isn't `padding euivalent to internal indentation.`

By the way, how can indent my text without the need to modify my div width ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to have a look at **[`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing)**.

It would make the `padding:` be calculated inside of the box's width.

Also read about the **[CSS Box Model](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/)**.

Answer (score 1):

```
#rightheader{
    float: right;
    width: 70%;   
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #336699;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-indent: 40px;
}
```